# How do you properly model a JSON map in android

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to pass a map from Firestore into a data class but I'm getting null instead of the data

This is how my data is accessed:

```
 firestoreDb = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
    val postsRef = firestoreDb
        .collection("posts")
        .limit(20)
        .orderBy("creation_time_ms", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)
        .orderBy("date", Query.Direction.DESCENDING)

    postsRef.addSnapshotListener { snapshot, exception ->
        if (exception != null || snapshot == null) {
            Log.e(TAG,"Exception when querying post", exception )
            return@addSnapshotListener
        }
        val postList = snapshot.toObjects(HousePost::class.java)
        for (post in postList) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Posts $post")
        }
    }
```

My model for the data

```
    data class HousePost (
   @get:PropertyName("image_url")  @set:PropertyName("image_url") var postImage: String = "",
   var rent: String = "",
   var description: String = "",
   @get:PropertyName("creation_time_ms")  @set:PropertyName("creation_time_ms") var creationTimeMs: Long = 0L,
   var location: String = "",
   @get:PropertyName("post_id")  @set:PropertyName("post_id")var postId: String? = "",
   var rooms: String = "",
   var caption: String = "",
   var date: String = "",
   var owner: Owner? = null
)
```

My Owner model class

```
class Owner(
var uid: String = "",
var username: String = "",
var email: String = "",
@get:PropertyName("profile_image") @set:PropertyName("profile_image")  var profileImage: String = "",
@get:PropertyName("user_type") @set:PropertyName("user_type")var usertype: String = "owner"
```

)

Here is my [firestore data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kk8ui.png) I know some fields are an empty string but that shouldn't output null.
This is the result from logcat

> 2022-05-03 11:42:12.313 6581-6581/com.example.moveapplication I/MainActivity: Posts HousePost(postImage=https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/moveapplicationdb.appspot.com/o/Post%20Pictures%2Fian-dooley-_-JR5TxKNSo-unsplash.jpg?alt=media&token=6721ec57-7602-41ee-b7cd-b8b1838b27fc, rent=15000, description=Along Ngong road we have a studio room for you to rent. Located in a moder =n area with nice infrastrucure, creationTimeMs=1651561930185, location=Lenana, postId=, rooms=studio room, caption=studio room along Ngong road, date=03/05/2022, owner=null)

My [index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7j9i.png) from firestore

Comment: post owner poko of `Owner`

Comment: Please edit your question and add the content of your `Owner` class. Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo I've added the Owner class

Comment: Unfortunately it did not fix the bug @AlexMamo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your class definitions, all look fine. You're using the correct annotations. However, when you're using the following query:

```
val postsRef = firestoreDb
    .collection("posts")
    .limit(20)
```

You'll need to know that you have to create an [index](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing). It can be manually created inside the [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/) or if you are using Android Studio, you'll find a message in the logcat that sounds like this:

> FAILED_PRECONDITION: The query requires an index. You can create it here: ...

Simply click on that link or copy and paste the URL into a web browser and your index will be created automatically for you.

Comment: Will it fix my "owner=null" bug?

Comment: What will work only after you set the proper index. Give it a try and tell me f it works.

Comment: Have you created the corresponding index? Edit your question and show it to us.

Comment: My question is updated

Comment: If you change `Log.i(TAG, "Posts $post")` to `Log.i(TAG, "Posts ${post.location"})`, are you getting the desired result?

Comment: Yes I am getting the locations correclty

Comment: So in that case, your problem sounds like it is solved, right?

Comment: Yes it is solved